# Handle JavaScript api response property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, object, fetch-api

I am a beginner and trying to fetch data from an API. When I try to map the response values some of its values for a specific key are undefined and it throws an error of **Cannot read property '0' of undefined** I have tried various methods but nothing is working for me.
Here is the code

```
const showEverything=(artist, album,mytracks) => {
let everythingObj={
    name    :[],
    title   :[],
    album   :[],
    id      :[]
}

// push the artist search result to my everythingObj
const recordings=artist.recordings;
recordings.map((record) => {
const { "artist-credit": credit } = record;
//here  it shows the error
const { "release-group": album } = record.releases[0]

everythingObj.name.push(credit[0].name);
everythingObj.title.push(record.title);
everythingObj.album.push(album.title);
everythingObj.id.push(record.releases[0].id);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways but one way is you can put checks

```
if(record && record.releases && record.releases[0])
const { "release-group": album } = record.releases[0]


credit[0] && credit[0].name && everythingObj.name.push(credit[0].name);
record && record.title && everythingObj.title.push(record.title);
album && album.title && everythingObj.album.push(album.title);
record && record.releases[0] && record.releases[0].id && everythingObj.id.push(record.releases[0].id);
```

You can more simplify above conditions based on your usage.

With above checks it won't push data any value if data is not there also will resolve errors.

Comment: @ali-raza Please try above condition and see if it helps you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the API does not return an array when we expect it to.
You can throw in an `if (condition)` to check if it exists first.

```
if (recordings.releases) {
    /* your code */
}
else {
    console.log('Blank response from API')
}
```

ref: [MDN - Falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: The recordings array exits but it has a property record.releases[0]. Its value is undefined on some occasions

Comment: @Ali You can handle such ocassions using conditions.

Comment: I am using the following condition but the error is still the same.
`if(record.releases[0]){
       const { "release-group": album } = record.releases[0]
       everythingObj.album.push(album.title);

    }
    else
    {
       everythingObj.album.push('undefinded');
    }`

Comment: @Ali Try `if(record.releases) {}`. You can aditionally check with a nested `if(record.releases.length != 0)` since JS does not consider empty array as a falsy value (refer the linked MDN doc), but this is completely dependent on your use-case.

Comment: I did, the error directly goes to the line `const { "release-group": album } = record.releases[0]`